# 3D Mesh Joining

Tags: graphics, algorithm, 3d, polygon

I have 2 (or more) intersecting meshes, which require joining into 1 mesh object. I want to have some control over the resulting seam vertex insertion, so looking to write myself rather than use a library.

Has anyone come across some open source code to base the algorithm on / ideas on the process? Initial impressions are:
1. Present in every 3D modelling program -> mostly reinventing existing process (hence search for examples)
2. Potential for fiddly-ness around the polygon face direction and just touching conditions. (see above point)

Answer (score 0):

Have you played with [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/)? It's advertised to expose boolean operations on general polyhedra, not just triangular meshes.  My own brief experience with it was that it's somewhat over-generic and over-designed, but it got the job done.

You you're willing to invest in studying open source modeling projects, [Blender](http://www.blender.org/development/) seems nice. Haven't looked inside myself.